# chef attributes value not getting parsed in another attribute

Tags: ruby, attributes, chef-infra

I am setting attributes in default.rb as

```
default[:my_app] = {
  :vol => "data02",
  :commitlog => "/foo/bar/node[:vol]/commitlog",
}
```

But `:vol` value is not getting parsed in commitlog attribute and I am getting following error.

```
mError executing action `create` on resource 'directory[/foo/bar/node[:vol]/comitlog]'[0m
```

Comment: `"/foo/bar/#{node[:vol]}/commitlog"` See documentation about [Ruby interpolation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the String interpolation syntax, e.g. `y = "The value of X is #{X}."` You probably want:

```
default[:my_app] = {
  :vol => "data02",
  :commitlog => "/foo/bar/#{node[:vol]}/commitlog",
}
```

Also, keep in mind that if you make one attribute depend on the value of another, you might override `node[:my_app][:vol]` later and expect the value of `node[:my_app][:commitlog]` to change with it, and it may not. The attributes will be parsed together, potentially before your override affects the first one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.Even after I am using the interpolation syntax, and when I am using node[:my_app][:commitlog] in recipe it shows /foo/bar//commitlog

Comment: Sounds like `node[:vol]` isn't what you think it is, or you missed the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Even after I am using the interpolation syntax, and when I am using node[:my_app][:commitlog] in recipe it shows /foo/bar//commitlog